# PHP preg_replace with multiple variables

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following short code I want to use to automatically generate Amazon Affiliate links in my posts `[amazon region=com asin=xxxxxx]`.

How can I get the 'region' a and 'asin' from this string and convert every occurrence of it into my php function `getAffiliateLink("com","xxxxxxxx")`?

I can have multiple of these strings with different numbers on the page.

I have been looking into preg_replace and regex but I can't figure out how to do this for this particular example.

Comment: elaborate your expected result: should it be literally `getAffiliateLink($region,$asin)` or `getAffiliateLink('com','xxxxxx')` ?

Comment: When for example I put `[amazon region=com asin=1234567]` then I want this to be replaced in my code with `getAffiliateLink("com","1234567")`. There can be more links like these in one post with different asin numbers. ( I edited my question to make it more clear)

Comment: You may want to show us your efforts on it.

Comment: @revo I am completely new to preg_replace. I have looked into regex and regular expressions, but I have no idea how to implement that for this case.

Comment: Are `region` and `asin` always in the same order? or it can be different?

Comment: They should always be in the same order yes.

Comment: Because I want to preg_replace with a PHP function, I already figured I will have to use preg_replace_callback(). Trying to figure out how now

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I found the solution. Because I want to replace the string with a function, I had to use `preg_replace_callback()`.

This is my working solution:

```
$content = preg_replace_callback('/\[amazon region=([^\b]+) asin=([^\b]+)\]/', 'callback', $content);

function callback ($matches) {
    print_r($matches);
    return getAffiliateLink("$matches[1]","$matches[2]");
}

echo $content;
```